# Email Assigned To Task in custom workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that based off of a List content type and I need to be able to send a customized email to the person who has been assigned the task. Problem is, 'Assigned To' does not exist as an option in the 'Add or Change Lookup' in the email creator within SharePoint Designer for workflows.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

In,the Data Source drop select the Current Task option. Then you will see the Assigned to field